# How to abort a package upload?

Tags: managed-package, upload

Is there a way to abort the upload of a managed package? After I clicked the Upload button I realized I have forget something. Do I have to wait and upload another package or is there a way to stop the current upload (at least in the mode where tests are running)?

Comment: The most stupid idea which has come to my mind is to have a test class named 'ZZZ' to be the last in test execution chain. Then introduce custom metadata like TestConf__mdt with boolean flag ForceTestFail__c, and make that ZZZ test class analyze it and passes/fails appropriately.  This way you would be able to fail upload process almost up to the last minute - but yeah, you would still need to wait for all tests to be executed. This doesn't save you time, it would just save major version number) Try looking into Test Execution view if tests execution are visible there while uploading.

Comment: @wesaw don't think this will work since the test won't be part of that uploading package. So it will never be kicked off.

Comment: @Basti Why not just make that ZZZ class part of the package. If it fails the Upload will fail. An a test can always access a custom setting in an org.